# Extract a substring from a text field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

New to TSQL and SQL generally, please pardon if this is really basic:

I am working with a new-to-me-database that has ignored some best practices.  Relevant to this discussion, some data is stored in a generalized note field, including loyalty numbers.  The good news is that the loyalty numbers are at least stored consistently within the note.

So, a simplified example from the note table might be:

[image]

I have verified that every Loyalty Number is stored consistently ("Loyalty Number ####"), but obviously this is not ideal.  I want to extract the Loyalty Number for every primary key that has them, then create a new field that stores the Loyalty Number.

What I'm having trouble with is the following: How do I run a query that will give me each primary key then, if there is a loyalty number return it, if not leave it null or say something like no result found.  E.g., turn the above into something like.

[image]

It's trivially easy to construct something like "select primary_key, note from note_table where note like '%Loyalty Number%', but that doesn't do the job of clipping down to just the loyalty number (and leaving out extraneous text).  The uniformity of the data means I could probably do this in Excel, but I'm wondering if it's possible in TSQL.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give something like this a try using `case` with `substring` and `charindex`:

```
select id,
    case when note like '%Loyalty Number [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
        then 'Loyalty Number ' + 
             substring(note, 
                   charindex('Loyalty Number', note) + Len('Loyalty Number ') + 1, 4) 
    end as Note  
from note
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e526/3)

The `case` statement checks to see if `Loyalty Number` exists in the data.  `Substring` splits the note field using `charindex` to find the starting position.  This is hard coding a length of 4 characters for the loyalty number.  Given your comments, this should work.  If you have a dynamic number of characters, you'll need to modify this slightly.

Comment: You could change `substring(note, 
                   charindex('Loyalty Number', note) + Len('Loyalty Number ') + 1, 4)` for `SUBSTRING(note,charindex('Loyalty Number',note),19)` as the length is fixed.

Comment: @jpw -- yes, I agree.  I used `len` in case the value of `Loyalty Number` could change (i.e. `Customer Since`).  Would make it a little easier to fix the normalization issues going on.  Appreciate the comment though!

Comment: And as I posted that, I realized the length of `Loyalty Number` and `Customer Since` are the same :D

Answer (score 1):

Building on @[segeddes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073631/sgeddes) answer, here's the rest of the code, that will update your new `LoyaltyNumber` column.

**Working SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36e46/8

```
UPDATE note_table
SET LoyaltyNumber = 
        CASE 
            WHEN note LIKE '%Loyalty Number [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
                THEN SUBSTRING(note, CHARINDEX('Loyalty Number', note) 
                 + LEN('Loyalty Number ') + 1, 4)
            ELSE 'Regular Customer'
        END 
FROM note_table
```

#### Table Definition and CRUD

```
CREATE TABLE note_table (
  id int identity(1,1), 
  Note VarChar(500),
  LoyaltyNumber varchar(20)
)

Insert Into note_table(Note) Values
('Customer Since 2012. Loyalty Number 4747'),
('Loyalty Number 2209'),
('Loyalty Number 2234.Customer Since 2009'),
('Pending Order');
```